# How to set auto increment value to another field using trigger

Tags: mysql

I need a solution for copy the `auto increment value` to `userid` column when insert the record.

I have two column like `id(AI)`,`userid`. Here I have used a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER adduserid BEFORE INSERT ON user
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.userid = NEW.id
```

The problems is `triggers` invoke `before insert`,so it will get id as 0.

Suggest me how can I modify the `trigger`?

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE departments (
ID           NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(50)  NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE departments ADD (
CONSTRAINT dept_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE SEQUENCE dept_seq;
```

Trigger definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_bir 
BEFORE INSERT ON departments 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
SELECT dept_seq.NEXTVAL
INTO   :new.id
FROM   dual;
END;
```

Syntax Link1:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: Yes i'm following the correct syntax. Suggest me the solution to copy autoincrement value to userid

Comment: explain me=>  table: column names, => adduserid.

Comment: Here table name is user, columns are id,userid, trigger name is adduserid

Comment: if i save a record,userid column will get the value of id(Autoincrement ID). Help me to write the trigger for tat

Comment: UPDATE user
SET  NEW.userid = NEW.id ;